# Python3 Selenium clear a text box in a table

Tags: css, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to clear a text box (textarea) with `Selenium` using `Python3`.

I have located the Text Box by

```
XPATH: //*[@name='scope']
```

I wish to clear the text in this element.

Here is the Code:

```
<table class="tdbglc" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="tdbgdc">
<tr class="tdbglc">
<td class="bodytextgray" width="3%" valign="top" height="30" align="center">2.</td>
<td class="bodytextgray" width="47%" valign="top" height="30" align="left">         Network Scope (Up to 30 IP subnets, one on each line):       </td>
<td class="bodytextgray" width="50%" height="30" colspan="2">
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" tabindex="2" name="scope">192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0</textarea>
```

*** Here is what I have tried: ***

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']").clear()
mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0')]").clear()
```

Still not clearing this element :( any ideas much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks for the feedback, Andy

**Thanks all for taking the time to comment.
Andy I tried:**

```
WebElement myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
myTextarea.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
myTextarea.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

**I now get this error:**

```
C:\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py
  File "C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py", line 41
    WebElement myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Apologies all I am newbie!

*** I think I am missing the point somewhere:**

In Both Andy's and Saurabh's comments the code word:

```
WebElement
```

looks to be producing an error.

I have tried:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
```

and the keyword looks to still error in PyCharm.

After adding:

```
WebElement myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
mydriver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", myTextarea)
```

I get a similar error as Andy's code:

```
C:\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py
  File "C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py", line 41
    WebElement myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I feel something is missing or my syntax is still broken in Python 3 for the word WebElement. '

Thanks

---

Thanks for the reply Saurabh.

**When I use just this code:**

```
myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
mydriver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", myTextarea)
```

**I get this ERROR:**

```
C:\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py", line 41, in <module>
    myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 745, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@name='scope']"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/gjones1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpk3yo6e94/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///C:/Users/gjones1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpk3yo6e94/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

** When I try Andy's code without the word WebElement **

```
myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
myTextarea.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a");
myTextarea.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);
```

I Get this error:

```
C:\Python\Python35\python.exe C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Python35/webtest4.py", line 41, in <module>
    myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 745, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@name='scope']"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/gjones1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp78badauy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///C:/Users/gjones1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp78badauy/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:625)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please Note I have re-confirmed the XPATH: //*[@name='scope']
finds the textbox.

Even when I change XPATH to something else that finds the textbox like:

```
//textarea[@tabindex='2']
//textarea[contains(@name,'scope')]
```

Same errors appear.

Thanks so far.

**Here is the FULL Code of the site:**

```
<html>
<head>
<frameset onload="frameLoad()" onbeforeunload="preUnloadPage()" onunload="pageUnload()" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" border="0" rows="65,0,*">
<frame noresize="" frameborder="NO" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="mainEx.jsp" name="nav">
<frame noresize="" frameborder="NO" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" src="empty.html" name="statusFrm">
<frame noresize="" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="blank.htm" name="ngbody">
<html>
<head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<div align="center">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0">
<form action="/common/discovery.do" method="POST" name="discoveryForm">
<table class="tdbglc" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr class="tdbgdc">
<tr class="tdbglc">
<td class="bodytextgray" width="3%" valign="top" height="30" align="center">2.</td>
<td class="bodytextgray" width="47%" valign="top" height="30" align="left"> Network Scope (Up to 30 IP subnets, one on each line): </td>
<td class="bodytextgray" width="50%" height="30" colspan="2">
<textarea rows="4" cols="40" tabindex="2" name="scope">192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0</textarea>
<img class="tooltip" src="../resource/skins/default/icons/help.png" tooltip="Discover devices that have IP addresses in the following subnets. At least one IP subnet in network/mask format (eg. <i>192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0</i> or <i>172.25.8.99/255.255.255.255</i>) must be specified, one on each row. When using the Seed Router option below, discovered devices not part of the specified subnets will be ignored (empty list will accept all)." style="float: right" data-hasqtip="1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tdbgdc">
<tr class="tdbglc">
<tr class="tdbgdc">
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="advancedOptionsTable" class="tdbglc" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<div id="advancedOptions" class="ui-helper-hidden">
<table class="tdbglc" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<br>
<br>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<input type="hidden" value="true" name="redrawn">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
</frame>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception??

Comment: Remove `WebElement`....just use without it..see updated answer..

Answer (score 0):

`.clear()` method works on a text area but if in your case `.clear()` is not working then you can execute `java script` to clear the `textarea` as below :-

```
myTextarea = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@name='scope']")
mydriver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", myTextarea)
```

Hope it will work for you...:)